# Get Meta Tags not work

Tags: php, html, meta-tags

I have this link `http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&template=php3.txt&IpAddress=`

and return the meta tags

`<meta name="known" content="true">`

```
<meta name="internet" content="EN">
```

and other. On page php i tried this

```
<?php 

$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&template=php3.txt&IpAddress=');


print $tags['city'];  // city name


?>
```

not work and return a white page why?

Comment: Have you activated error reporting?

Comment: with this code: ini_set("error_reporting", E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE); 
echo ini_get("error_reporting");  return error number 4181

Comment: Remove the `echo` from the `echo ini_get`. Can you add `print_r($tags)` to see whether any data is sent at all?

Comment: Warning: get_meta_tags(http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&template=php3.txt&IpAddress=xx.xxx) [function.get-meta-tags]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403

Comment: That sounds more like it. Geobytes doesn't seem to be allowing your request for whatever reason (maybe you need to authenticate first?)

Comment: like this http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm =(

Comment: `Basically you get the first 20 lookups per hour for free and then only pay 1 Mapbyte (@ 1 tenth of a cent) per look up after that. Click here to purchase 10,000 Mapbytes for $10 (Or click here to purchase via PayPal).` That is probably why it's denying access to you

Comment: ok i tried on c# for read the page html meta tags it is simple =) thanks so much

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30264/discussion-between-federal09-and-pekka-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Use:

```
print_r(
   get_meta_tags("http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&template=php3.txt&IpAddress=") 
);
```

Comment: $tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&template=php3.txt&IpAddress=');


echo $tags['city']; work